# How can I solve java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error when deploying Springboot + OracleDB WAR to Tomcat container?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, containers, external

I'm trying to access springboot application that interacts with oracledb. I'm trying access war file deployed into tomcat container. It's throwing me error java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection. Help me to solve the issue.

Its working locally when I ran java -jar Employeemanagement.war i.e (localhost:8080-I'm able to access the applcation and data is storing in oracledb). but when I deploy war to tomcat its throwing error.